# ExtJS specialKey event in MVC controller

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a very standard Login Form structured like this:

```
Window { id: idLogin,  
    Form {
      User Text Field 
      Password Text Field  
      Remember Me Check Box 
    }   
    Login Button 
}
```

---

Then, I wrote my controller like this:

```
Ext.define('My.controller.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    //working   
    init: function(application) {
        this.control({
            "#idLogin button":   {click: this.onButton},
            "#idLogin form > *": {specialKey: this.onKey}
        });
    },
    //working
    onButton: function(button, e, eOpts) {
        //...
    },
    //not working
    onKey: function (field, el) {
        if (el.getKey() == Ext.EventObject.ENTER) //...
    }
});
```

---

The `init` and `onButton`functions are working. However, my specialKey `onKey` function doesn't seem to hook up with the view. I tried `"#idLogin form > *"`, `"#idLogin form > textfield"`, or just `"#idLogin form"` none is working, I am not sure why. Please help?

Comment: Johan is right, the event is 'specialkey' with a lowercase K

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The events are case sensitive I think, it's `specialkey` with the K as lowercase http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-event-specialkey. Do you want every form field btw? Because you can make your listener like this: `#idLogin form [isFormField]` to get all form fields within your form.